# Ошибка записи даты в Room DataBase

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Помогите разобраться. 
Реализовала запись даты в EditText  с помощью DatePickerDialog следующим образом:

```
 private EditText mDisplayDate;
public static final String TAG = "EditActivity";
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
    mDisplayDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDate);
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(EditActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        }
    };
```

Использую для записи данных Room DataBase. До этого у меня получалось корректно выводить заданные данные вещественного типа в список.

```
@Entity (tableName = "Directory_list")
public class Directory {
@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
private  int id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "date")
private int date;
@ColumnInfo(name = "value")
private float value;
@ColumnInfo (name = "power")
private float power;
```

До того, как я захотела вывести дату полученную в edDate.
Предыдущие параметры я преобразовывала в тип String для вывода в TextView следующим образом:

```
 public void setData(Directory directory) {
        tvDate.setText(String.valueOf(parameter.getDate()));
        tvValue.setText(String.valueOf(parameter.getValue())); 
        tvPower.setText(String.valueOf(parameter.getPower()));
```

Так же в моем DataAdapter я объявляю откуда брать данные:

```
 private void init()
{
    myDB = AppDataBase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mDisplayDate = findViewById(R.id.edDate);
    edValue = findViewById(R.id.edValue);
    edPower = findViewById(R.id.edPower);

}
```

При этом при запуске моего приложение я заполняю данные в edit_layout, но при перезапуске они не выводятся в списке (обновление страницы еще не реализовала). И в логах выходит слеюущее:

> "2020-04-26 17:55:27.431 28496-28554/com.example.forma E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1"

В чем может быть проблема?
До того, как я захотела выводить дату, все корректно в списке выводилось.
Возможно когда в DataAdapter я указываю откуда брать значения нужно вместо  mDisplayDate  нужно указать edDate?
Пробовала так, но при это приложение вообще вылетало.

Comment: Добавьте код, как вы сохраняете эту дату в базу данных.

Comment: Спасибо я разобралась. В моем случае необходимо дату передавать с типом String